# Eclipse Source Menu disappears immediately after startup

Tags: eclipse

I have a new clean install of eclipse (CodeReady 12.17.0) and upon startup in a new workspace, the 'Source' menu appears for a second, see screen shot below.

[image: On Startup showing Source menu]

But within a second the Source menu is gone and even after creating a project it does not return...

[image: No Source Menu even after creating project]

Even after customizing the perspective to make the Source menu Visible, the Source menu items are greyed with an XML source file open.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works for Java files but not XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Source menu only applies to Java source files and is not shown when other file types are being edited.

I think it appears briefly during startup as it is part of the default set of menus for the perspective. It is then hidden when it is determined that no Java source file is being edited.

Comment: In addition to the Java editor there are some more editors that populate the _Source_ menu with their items.

Comment: Well in previous versions it did show when XML files are being edited, such as camel blueprint.xml

Comment: There are a number of specialist editors which can be associated with XML files, some may have their own Source menu, perhaps it was one of those.